# How to add a sub-document field with a condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to add a new subField with a condition.
In the case the field already exists, I don't overwrite it.
In the case the condition is not fulfilled, I don't want to add the parent object.

Here is my collection :

```js
{type: "A", object: {a: "", b: "foo"}},
{type: "A", object: {a: ""}},
{type: "A"},
{type: "B"}
```

Here is my aggregate :

```js
{
  $addFields: {
    "object.b": {
      $cond: {
        if: {$eq: ["$type","A"]},
        then: {$ifNull: ["$object.b", "bar"]},
        else: "$DROP"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

$DROP is not an aggregate command, but in the else case I don't want to add the new field.
It will not create the `b` field, but the parent object remains.

Here is my current result :

```js
{type: "A", "object": {a: "", b: "foo"}},
{type: "A", "object": {a: "", b: "bar"}},
{type: "A", "object": {b: "bar"}},
{type: "B", "object": {}},
```

Here is what I want :

```js
{type: "A", object: {a: "", b: "foo"}},
{type: "A", object: {a: "", b: "bar"}},
{type: "A", object: {b: "bar"}},
{type: "B"}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregate query will give you the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        object: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ "$type", "A" ] },
                then: { 
                    $mergeObjects: [ 
                        "$object",  
                        { b: { $ifNull: [ "$object.b", "bar" ] } } 
                    ] 
                },
                else: "$$REMOVE"
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Note the `$$REMOVE` is a aggregation system variable.

Comment: if `{type : "B", object {...}}` this will remove the object needs fixing.Needs one more if/else i think in the place of  "$$REMOVE"

Answer (score 1):

When a `$set` adds a path, all path is added, even if you end up to `$$REMOVE` this will affect only the last of the path, the rest would be already added [see example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OPsN8ycCIpY)

Query

- `$set` with switch case starting from object
- if object doesn't exist

  - if type A add `{object :{"b" : "bar"}}`
  - else `$$REMOVE`
- $type = "A" AND (not-value "$object.b")
  add `{"b" : "bar"}` (this case covers also the case object:null)
- else
  keep old value (another type, or b had value)

*Maybe it could be smaller but we check many things(see the example for all cases of data)

- object exists/null/not exists
- type A/not
- b exists/null/value

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVMJLyVu1i5)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "object": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$object"
                  },
                  "missing"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$type",
                      "A"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "b": "bar"
                  },
                  "$$REMOVE"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$type",
                      "A"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$or": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$object.b",
                          null
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          {
                            "$type": "$object.b"
                          },
                          "missing"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$object",
                  {
                    "b": "bar"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "default": "$object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```